# How do I deal with these errors when using the Hugin command line tools?

Tags: software, hugin, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch images through command line of Hugin as outlined here: http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell#Simple_command-line_stitching

I did the first step to create control points; that is:

```
autopano-sift-c --projection 0,50 project.pto DSC_1234.JPG DSC_1235.JPG DSC_1236.JPG
```

But when I write this command:

```
celeste_standalone -i project.pto -o project.pto
```

This error comes:

```
Couldn't open SVM model file celeste.model
```

Also tried `G:/huginbase/hugin-huild/INSTALL/FILES/share/hugin/data/celeste.model`

Also for optimizer command, they say HFOV value is invalid. I tried using

```
autooptimiser -v 50 -a -l -s -m -o optimised.pto project.pto
```

and still the same error occurred.

What is this error and what should I do to avoid it?

Comment: Hi koder, welcome to the forum. Your question, though related to photography, is actually about coding, so is more suited to the forum at http://stackoverflow.com which deals specifically with questions like this. You'll find more people with the relevant expertise who can help you out there. One of the moderators here should be able to migrate your question accordingly.

Comment: @NickMiners: The question is pretty specifically about post-processing photos with Hugin, even though its done with a command line. There is not actually any "programming" involved in the question here...just a bunch of command lines. Just because a command line is involved does not mean this is not photographic post processing, and as far as I can tell, this question is entirely on-topic. We have several members here who use hugin regularly, and one of them should be able to answer this.

Comment: This isn't about coding, it's just asking how to use command line options in a program.  He might get an answer there, but I don't feel it's a programming question at all.

Comment: koder, could you tell us if you're running on a Mac or Windows, and where you have hugin installed?  Can you look and tell us the exact path where the file celeste.model is located?

Comment: @NickMiners: N/P. Just wanted to make sure this didn't get closed, and make sure the community in general understood that even if a command line is involved, it can still be considered part of "photography" when referring to tools like Hugin or exiftool, etc.

Comment: If we take software GUI questions (and we do), we should take these too!

Comment: Searching for the error it seems to Mac related (https://bugs.launchpad.net/hugin/+bug/789934) The bug expired due to inactivity but seems its related to content not being where it should be. My best bet would be to make sure the files it is looking for is in the correct location. Also by looking at where he is running the app from it seems to be on a windows machine

Comment: Also posted on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960034/command-line-stitching-through-hugin

Comment: @MikeW : I am using Windows. I havent installed Hugin. I have just extracted the files from a zip folder on to my desktop. celeste.model is in the directory \hugin\share\hugin\data\                  
I dint install hugin because when the installed version doesnt have autopano-sift-c.exe in the bin folder.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...have you tried using backslash rather than slash in the path for the .model file? In windows, path delimiter is \, not /...perhaps hugin does not recognize the use of slash, and literally cannot find the path?

Comment: @koder: Are you still having trouble here? Have you figured out the problem? If you have, could you answer your own question with the resolution, in case anyone has this problem in the future?

Comment: @jrista: I havent found the solution till now. 
Please help if possible

Comment: Could you please indicate exactly what version number of Hugin you are using?

Answer (score 5):

The command line you typed for celeste should work. What I would look into next is:

- Confirm that the file celeste.model is in the same folder as celeste_standalone.exe
- Look from what path you are calling it, and possibly adding the hugin\bin folder in the path for your command line 'SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\huginFolder\bin' Having it in the bin saved me from trouble a few times.

As for the HFOV value is invalid, your command line seems ok. Here is one I know works
'autooptimiser.exe -a  -o "output.pto" "input.pto"'

Can you add more info, specifically the first few lines of your input PTO file, something like:

p f2 w3000 h1500 v360  n"JPEG q90"
m g1 i0

i w3168 h4752 f0 a0 b-0.01 c0 d0 e0 p0 r0 v180 y0  u10 n"IMG_2415.tif"
i w3168 h4752 f0 a=0 b=0 c=0 d0 e0 p0 r0 v=0 y0  u10 n"IMG_2416.tif"